# Serial does not receive all chars

Tags: serial, communication, string, serial-data

I'm trying to follow [Serial Input Basics](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-input-basics/278284/2) to build a program which receives commands over serial like `"<led:12,34,21>"` but i'm stuck on receiving the characters from serial...

I have copied the code from the example for `receiveWithStartAndEndMarkers` but it does not show that i received all the characters over serial

```
const int kMaxCommandSize=30;
char receivedChars[kMaxCommandSize + 1];
char command[kMaxCommandSize + 1];
boolean newData = false;

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop() {
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  if(newData){
    ProcessCommand();
    newData = false;
  }
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;
 
 // if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= kMaxCommandSize) {
                    ndx = kMaxCommandSize - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        } else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

void ProcessCommand() {
  Serial.println("Received:");
  Serial.println(receivedChars);
}
```

But when i send `<123>` i am consistently seeding

```
Received:
1
Received:
1
Received:
1
```

or when i send `<asdf1234>` i see

```
Received:
a
Received:
a
Received:
a
```

EDIT: it looks like sometimes the full transmission works... But not often i just sent `<123>` four times and got

```
Received:
123
Received:
12
Received:
1
Received:
123
```

Comment: Your provided sketch is not complete and does not compile, how and where is `kMaxCommandSize` defined? -- OT: I _love_ this safe comparisons for booleans, you should make sure that it really works: `(newData == false) == true`. ;-) Hint: if it does not read nice, consider to rename the variable, for example to `hasNewData`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. On my Uno, with the added line `const int kMaxCommandSize = 32;` it works perfectly.

Comment: Which Arduino are you testing it on?

Comment: @thebusybee sorry, kMaxCommandSize can be replaced by 30

Comment: @NickGammon I tried on a Mega (where the issue originally occurred), and a Uno. On the Uno it doesnt even reply! Its like the messages go no where.... Maybe both of them are bad...

Comment: You may try a simpler program that just echoes whatever it receives: `void loop(){if(Serial.available())Serial.write(Serial.read());}`. If it's still unreliable, look at the TX and RX pins with an oscilloscope.